# How to resolve "Download is disallowed" error in Lightning Web Component on Salesforce Community Page?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, community-builder

I have a Lightning Web Component that generates a temporary link element to trigger a file download. But, when I try to use it on a Salesforce Community Page, it throws the error

**"Download is disallowed. The frame initiating or instantiating the download is sandboxed, but the flag ‘allow-downloads’ is not set. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280 for more details."**

How can I resolve this issue?

```js
// Create a temporary link element and trigger the download
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = fileName.split('/').pop();;
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
document.body.removeChild(link);
```